# How to use helm-semantic-or-imenu for code navigation with type annotated python code

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, emacs-helm, emacs-semantic, imenu

I would like to use the helm-semantic-or-imenu command to navigate components of type annotated Python code, but whatever code analyzer is used to dentify the components doesn't seem to recognize the type annotated python code. Functions with the return type annotation doesn't get recognized at all and functions with annotated arguments show the type instead of the arguments names in the signatures [image: see screenshot]

The main problem I have is that I do not properly understand the components that is involved in making this work (when it does work). Obviously it might help to somehow update the code analyzer, but in which project do I find that? helm? semantic? imenu? or as someone mentioned somewhere else with regards to code analysis python.el? I could really use some help getting started to solve this. If the code analyzer is found in python.el, can I then try to modify and make emacs use a local version preferentially over the installed one?

EDIT:
After making the initial post I finally made a break through in trying to figure out where the components come from. I searched for python*.el in all of the file systemsystem and discovered these:

./usr/share/emacs/26.2/lisp/cedet/semantic/wisent/python.elc
./usr/share/emacs/26.2/lisp/cedet/semantic/wisent/python-wy.elc

I found the source for emacs 26.2 and discovered that indeed it seems python-el is responsible for parsing python files for semantic. It also internally uses the python-wy for recognizing a large portion of the language components. But unfortunately that is where I hit a brick wall. I was hoping to be able to monkey patch the function that recognizes a function definition via an re or something, but semantic actually solves the problem *the right way*. So python-wy seems to be auto-generated from a formal grammar definition file (in emacs git admin/grammars/python.wy) and figuring out how to modify **that** it is unfortunately much beyond my abilities.

Comment: are you trying to use semantic or imenu? The code analyzer for semantic is in the semantic library, python.el provides an imenu function that finds all the function names, but wont provide the arguments/types.  If `(semantic-active-p)` is non-nil in your python buffer, then `helm-semantic-or-imenu` will prefer semantic over imenu

Comment: @jenesaisquoi thanks for replying. So now understanding, that it is an option to use one of the other, I would say that it doesn't matter to which function provides components for the search, as long as that component recognizes the type annotated function definitions. Obviously the argument names would be nice to have, but not required. Evaluating `(semantic-active-p)` in the python buffer above returns `t`. I tried to set it to `nil` with `(setq semantic-active-p nil)`but unsuccessfully. How do I modify it? Apologies for my bad elisp foo, but I was always more of an emacs user than modder.

Comment: no worries, the cedet/semantic package is probably the most complicated code you could find in base emacs.  Personally I only enable it for C/C++, but out of the box it will be active in some other modes including python. Imenu usually uses a simple regex as you mention in your edit to find jump locations

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I should also mention, that while I was unable to modify the `semantic-active-p` variable I did try calling `imenu` directly and it gave the same sarch results.

Comment: yea, because once you activate semantic for python (loading the wisent file) it will set the value for the `imenu-create-index-function` annoyingly -- this is a bug IMHO

Comment: **Thank you, thank you, thank you**. So I tried starting emacs up without my .emacs and use imenu and that showed **all** the functions. I then went into my .emacs and just commented out the line that activated semantic-mode for python files, and there you go, the helm-semantic-or-imenu now displays all the results. Simple enough solution, but I would not have been able to find it without your input on how this thing is put together. I'm a little unsure about the stackoverflow etiquette here, but if you put that into an answer I will of course mark it as the solving answer.

Comment: glad it worked for you. The reason I think it's a bug is - even if you don't activate semantic in your python hook, but you use it for C/C++ or something - when you open a C/C++ buffer the imenu variables will still be set in python buffers unless specifically tell semantic not to setup those mode buffers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic python backend doesn't appear to parse type annotations correctly (and there hasn't been much recent development on those libraries as far as I can tell).  Since `helm-semantic-or-imenu` favors semantic when it is active, you can disable semantic altogether for python buffers unless you use its other features (personally I only use it for C/C++).

When the semantic mode-specific libraries are loaded they set `imenu-create-default-create-index` and `imenu-default-goto-function`, causing imenu to use semantic instead of python.el's imenu function.

To disable semantic support for your python files you can customize the `semantic-new-buffer-setup-functions`, only adding entries for modes you want semantic support for, eg. in your semantic hook (or alternatively with the customize UI),

```
(setq semantic-new-buffer-setup-functions
      '((c-mode                . semantic-default-c-setup)
        (c++-mode              . semantic-default-c-setup)
        (srecode-template-mode . srecode-template-setup-parser)
        (texinfo-mode          . semantic-default-texi-setup)
        ;; etc.
        ;; (makefile-automake-mode . semantic-default-make-setup)
        ;; (makefile-mode         . semantic-default-make-setup)
        ;; (makefile-gmake-mode   . semantic-default-make-setup)
        ))
```